# ArrayStoreException when trying to set an element of an array to a superclass object

Tags: java, arrays, object, memory, compiler-construction

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

Hi, I'm learning Java and I'm trying to understand why this works:

```
A[] tab = new A[10];
tab[0] = new B();
```

and not this:

```
A[] tab = new B[10];
tab[0] = new A();
```

this line `A[] tab = new B[10];` means that the compiler is booking 10 places for B in memory. `tab[0] = new A()` is setting `tab[0]` equal to a new `A` object that is smaller (?) than `B` (`B extends A`).

Why is there an `ArrayStoreException: A` error ? How does it work ?

Comment: Think about it. If `Dog extends Animal` then dog is an animal, but not all animals are dogs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store subclasses of an object, inside that object. ie `B` can be stored in `A`, but `A` is a superclass of type `B`. Basically, any class below class `X` in the inheritance chain can be referred to as type `X`, but any class above class `X` in the inheritance chain can NOT be referred to as type `X`.

**Your example**

```
A[] tab = new A[10]; // Perfectly fine. Equal objects.
tab[0] = new B(); // B is a subclass of A, so this is allowed.

A[] tab = new B[10]; // Same principle as above, B is a subclass of A
tab[0] = new A(); // A is a SUPERCLASS of B, so it can not be referred to as A
```

In short, `X` can only be referred to as `Y`, if `X` is a subclass of `Y`. (Or a subclass of a subclass. It's a recursive definition).

**Let's use some English terms**

Instead of `A` and `B`, let's have `Item` and `Book`.

```
public class Item {}

public class Book extends Item {}
```

Now, it makes sense to say:

```
Item b = new Book(); // All Books are items.
```

It does not make sense to say:

```
Book b = new Item(); // All items are definitely not books.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made **to store the wrong
>   type of object into an array of objects**. For example, the following
>   code generates an ArrayStoreException:

```
Object x[] = new String[3]; 
x[0] = new Integer(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

*"My Animal array will contain only Butterflies (`A[] tab = new B[10];`). Add a new Animal in the array (`tab[0] = new A();`)."*

How to be sure the inserted Animal is a Butterfly?

Answer (score 1):

The thumb rule in java is superclass reference variable can point to sub class object and not vice versa, if you think about it , it makes sense that parent class can point to child class object. List list = new ArrayList()

Answer (score 1):

Because if B extends A, B has ALL of the A characteristics (attributes, methods, etc), PLUS his own.

Then each B is also an A, while an A (that would lack the characteristics of B) is NOT a B.

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to the most essential property of a hierarchical type system, which is the *Liskov Substitution Principle*: wherever an instance of A is allowed, an instance of any of its subtypes is also allowed. Arrays are no special case.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
class A { }

class B extends A { }
```

We have:

```
A [] a = new A [10]; // can store A or B objects

A [] b = new B [10]; // can only store B objects
```