# Beginner Array of Objects Confusion

Tags: java, arrays, oop, polymorphism

I am having trouble understanding what is actually happening when I declare the array in the following code.

```
class Type1 {

}

class Type2 extends Type1 {
    public void method2() {

    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Type1[] x = new Type2[2];
        x[0] = new Type1(); // runtime error
        x[1] = new Type2();
        x[1].method2(); // syntax error

    }
}
```

I thought since the right-hand side of the array declaration is `new Type2[2]` that the array would consist of reference variables of the type `Type2`. If this is true, the first error makes sense because I cannot have a subtype referring to a supertype.

However, why does the second error occur two lines after that? Isn't `method2()` known by Type2, so the method is known by the reference variable? It seems it is because `Type1` doesn't know `method2`, so does that mean the array consists of reference variables of the type `Type1`? If this is true, why does the first error occur as it is no longer a subtype referring to a supertype?

Also, why is the first error a runtime error while the other is a syntax error?

Please note I am only in my second programming course, so my terminology may be a little off.

Edit: The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914132/arraystoreexception-when-trying-to-set-an-element-of-an-array-to-a-superclass-ob) does not answer my question because it does not answer why an element of an array like `x` cannot invoke `method2()` even though an element of `x` of `Type 2`. My question is different because of this and because my question also asks why the first error occurs when the second error also occurs (why an element of `x` cannot refer to and object of the type `Type1` and at the same time cannot invoke `method2()`). I originally thought that if one error occurred, then the other cannot occur. I wanted a comparison between the two errors and a more in-depth explanation than simply the rules of polymorphism.

Comment: For a beginner, this is a very good question indeed.

Comment: The second error is somewhat unrelated to the first and arrays - you'd get the same error with the non-array equivalent - `Type1 x = new Type2(); x.method2();`

Comment: Your question is answered in [ArrayStoreException when trying to set an element of an array to a superclass object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16914132) and [Why do I get a compile-time error when calling a subclass method using super class reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37853463)

Comment: Related: [Call a method of subclass in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2701182)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is one of those weird things that Java allows you to do, assigning an array of a derived class to a variable of array of the base class.

In your code, `x` at compile time is of type `Type1[]`. That's what the compiler thinks it is. At runtime, `x` is of type `Type2[]`, but the compiler does not know that.

The first error occurs at runtime because as you said, you can't assign `Type1` to a variable of type `Type2`.

But the second error occurs at compile time because the compiler still thinks that `x` is of type `Type1`, and there is no method called `method2` in `Type1`, even though `x` actually holds a `Type2[]` at runtime.

To call `method2`, you need to tell the compiler that `x[1]` is of type `Type2` by casting:

```
((Type2)x[1]).method2();
```

Lesson of the day? Don't do this:

```
Superclass[] array = new Subclass[2];
```

You'll get yourself in trouble.

Comment: _x at compile time is of type Type1[]. That's what the compiler thinks it is. At runtime, x is of type Type2[], but the compiler does not know that._ +1

Comment: @Sweeper add covariance to the plate, to make it even more confusing

Answer (score 6):

A super-type reference can refer to a sub-type. I think you understand this, since the first error is coherent to you.

The second error stems from the fact that at compile time, `x` is still a `Type1[]`. This means that at run-time the reference can hold any sub-type, including a type that doesn't have the method `method2`. That's why you can only use the methods defined in `Type1`.

You could, for example, check whether the type is actually `Type2` at runtime using `isInstanceOf`, and then cast it to a `Type2` and then use `method2`.
There are usually better solutions, though.

Answer (score 0):

to put it in layman terms for the below code,

```
Type1[] x = new Type2[2];
```

let us just take `Type1 x = new Type2;` *not arrays, just classes.*

**What do you infer from the above step?**

Here x is a reference variable. We are creating an object of "Type2" and x has the reference of the Object Type2 *[lets just say, x is a remote control pointing to Type2 object]*. Dont forget that, x is of the type 'Type1', which means it does not have a 'method2()' button on its remote control.[Remember, method2 is of Type2 Class not Type1].

Compiler calls a method on an object,only when it sees it inside the class.  compiler does not care which Object you are creating [*here*: new Type2], all it cares is on whom you are making the call (*here: x[1], which is of type Type1*). So, it throws the compile time error. It does not bother what happens at runtime or which object it is pointing to, **all it cares is if Whether the reference type has the calling method or not [*In Our terminology, does the remote control has that button*]?**.

> why is the first error a runtime error while the other is a syntax
>   error?

I hope the above explanation, (*when you consider Array types as per your question*)  answers your second half of the question.

**And, as for the first part**, you pretty much answered it. Anyhow, thing is Arrays allow this kind of stuff and blows up at Runtime whereas, Arraylist do it at compile time.[That is a part of Generics].

As you said,you are new to this stuff, here is my reference for You.

**Reference:**

Head First Java